# Precalculating ThreeJSymbols to make my program faster

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation

Does anybody have an idea what is the best way to pre-calculate the `ThreeJSymbols` in order to use them in a loop? (I want to make my program work faster that is why I need to precalculate the values for `ThreeJSymbols` and just read them in the loop)

```
ne = 6
ℓ0 = 2
ns = 10
γ =  Join[Table[{m, 1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}],  Table[{m, -1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}]]
vdir = ParallelTable[
  mi = γ[[i, 1]]; 
  mj = γ[[j, 1]];
  μi = γ[[i, 2]];
  μj = γ[[j, 2]];
  If[μi == μj, 
    Total[Table[Off[ClebschGordan::phy];
      mk = γ[[k, 1]];
      ip = mk - mi + mj;
      N[ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ0,  mi}, {ℓ0, -mj}, {ℓtot, -mi + mj}]*
       (-1)^(  mk - mi)  * ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ0, -mk}, {ℓ0,  ip}, {ℓtot, mi - mj}]*
       ThreeJSymbol[{ℓ0, 0}, {ℓ0, 0}, {ℓtot, 0}]^2],
     {ie, 1, ne}, {ℓtot, 0, 2 ℓ0} , {k, 1, ns}], 
     Infinity], 0]
 , {i, 1, ns}, {j, 1, ns}]
```

I tried to use Compile also, but because of different array sizes I am getting for ThreeJSymbols I am not quiet sure how to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try memoization. This defines a function `f` that remembers formerly used arguments along with their values. Each  computational kernel has its own version of `f` so that they don't have to interfer with each other (communication between kernels usually kills all advantages from parallelization).

```
ParallelEvaluate[
  Off[ClebschGordan::phy];
  ClearAll[f];
  f[a_, b_, c_] := (f[a, b, c] = N@ThreeJSymbol[a, b, c]);
  ];
```

Now let's perform the computation in parallel. I also took the freedom to refactor the code here and there. For example, I split the outer loop `ParallelTable` into a `ParallelTable` and a `Table` so that the read operations for the `i`-index have to be computed only once per inner loop.

```
ne = 6
ℓ0 = 2
ns = 10
γ = Join[Table[{m, 1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}], Table[{m, -1}, {m, -ℓ0, ℓ0}]];
vdir = ParallelTable[
    mi = γ[[i, 1]];
    μi = γ[[i, 2]];
    Table[
     mj = γ[[j, 1]];
     μj = γ[[j, 2]];
     If[μi == μj,
      Sum[
       mk = γ[[k, 1]];
       ip = mk - mi + mj;
       Times[
        f[{ℓ0, mi}, {ℓ0, -mj}, {ℓtot, -mi + mj}],
        (-1)^(mk - mi),
        f[{ℓ0, -mk}, {ℓ0, ip}, {ℓtot, mi - mj}],
        f[{ℓ0, 0}, {ℓ0, 0}, {ℓtot, 0}]^2
        ],
       {ie, 1, ne}, {ℓtot, 0, 2 ℓ0}, {k, 1, ns}],
      0.
      ],
     {j, 1, ns}],
    {i, 1, ns}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.097378

Successive runs will be even faster because the values of `f` are already precomputed.

Comment: Hello Henrik, Thank you so much. Can you tell me also how does Compile work here if I want to use it @Henrik Schumacher

Comment: That's not that easy because `ThreeJSymbols` is not compilable...